# Select Rows Between Start and End Column (Unix timestamps)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that takes a Unix Timestamp (i.e. 1396396810 = 4/1/2014 6:00:10 PM) and check a table to see if that date falls between the `start` and `end` columns.

1396332000 = 4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM

1396504800 = 4/3/2014 12:00:00 AM

I have table `deposit_dates`

```
id | start | end | status
--------------------------
1  | 1396332000 | 1396504800 | 1
```

And I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM deposit_dates
WHERE start >= 1396396810
AND end <= 1396396810;
```

My problem is that the query returns 0 rows, when `1396396810` is between `1396332000` and `1396504800`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query needs to be

```
SELECT * FROM deposit_dates
WHERE start <= 1396396810
AND end >= 1396396810;
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear with my question. I've edited it above. I'm trying to see if a given timestamp is between the start and end columns.

Comment: yep. i edited my query.. the comparison operators had to be inverted.. your value needs to be greater than start date and less than end date. you had it in reverse.

Comment: you rock... o si hablas español, eres la raja!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

SELECT * FROM deposit_dates
WHERE  timestamp BETWEEN start AND end;